# data.table assigning output to a variable column

Tags: r, data.table

So I have a loop that I want to implement which assigns the original value (in row a and col b) + 1 if the value (at row a and col b) is equal to a certain number, however, when i try to assign the number using `with = FALSE`, I am unable to do so, and removing it yields me an output where the whole col is `=` to original value (in row a and col b) + 1.

Test Case:

```
a <- rep(0,6)
b <- 1:6
c <- -3:2
d <- runif(6)
e <-runif(6)
dt1 <- data.table("ID" = b,"code_a" = a,"code_c" = c, "code_d" = d, "code_e" = e)
dt1
   ID code_a code_c    code_d      code_e
1:  1      0     -3 0.5369538 0.269854945
2:  2      0     -2 0.7186787 0.009384648
3:  3      0     -1 0.8053726 0.831286263
4:  4      0      0 0.2084106 0.171294349
5:  5      0      1 0.0130021 0.730679582
6:  6      0      2 0.2902858 0.062175009
```

So in the following I have assigned `ctr <- 1` and tested the scenario that I wanted to replace `col_2` and `row_1` with the number 1, but unfortunately, neither scenario is my desired output.

My Attempt number 1:

```
dt1[,eval(ctr+1), with = FALSE][ctr] <- 1

Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, , eval(ctr + 1), with = FALSE, value = list( : 
  unused argument (with = FALSE)
```

My Attempt number 2:

```
dt1[,eval(ctr+1)][ctr] <- 1
> dt1
   ID code_a code_c    code_d      code_e
1:  1      1     -3 0.5369538 0.269854945
2:  2      1     -2 0.7186787 0.009384648
3:  3      1     -1 0.8053726 0.831286263
4:  4      1      0 0.2084106 0.171294349
5:  5      1      1 0.0130021 0.730679582
6:  6      1      2 0.2902858 0.062175009
```

Desired Output:

```
   ID code_a code_c    code_d      code_e
1:  1      1     -3 0.5369538 0.269854945
2:  2      0     -2 0.7186787 0.009384648
3:  3      0     -1 0.8053726 0.831286263
4:  4      0      0 0.2084106 0.171294349
5:  5      0      1 0.0130021 0.730679582
6:  6      0      2 0.2902858 0.062175009
```

This is probably asked before, but I am unable to find the correct way to find the thread that asked this question. I also tried using `..ctr` but to no success. If anyone can help me understand whats going on, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `set` with `i` and `j` index

```
set(dt1, i = as.integer(ctr), j = 2L, value = 1)
dt1
#   ID code_a code_c     code_d     code_e
#1:  1      1     -3 0.37168485 0.89323758
#2:  2      0     -2 0.44402352 0.70270947
#3:  3      0     -1 0.50800021 0.82133031
#4:  4      0      0 0.14904232 0.33997461
#5:  5      0      1 0.03376199 0.22633368
#6:  6      0      2 0.42361025 0.02377616
```

Comment: for the `value = 1L` is it possible to have a function inside that, like say the original value of that data +1 or the like?

Comment: @Kazusa12345 It is just integer representation.  If your column is numeric, just pass `1`

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind,I forgot about how to actually code in `data.frame` I should not be doing:

```
dt1[,eval(ctr+1), with = FALSE][ctr] <- 1
```

I should not be chaining here, as it is unecessary, but just use `data.frame` notation and :

```
dt1[eval(ctr),eval(ctr+1)] <- 1
```

And this gives me

```
   ID code_a code_c    code_d      code_e
1:  1      1     -3 0.5369538 0.269854945
2:  2      0     -2 0.7186787 0.009384648
3:  3      0     -1 0.8053726 0.831286263
4:  4      0      0 0.2084106 0.171294349
5:  5      0      1 0.0130021 0.730679582
6:  6      0      2 0.2902858 0.062175009
```

Comment: Why do you need `eval` ? `dt1[ctr, ctr + 1] <- 1` should be fine ?

Comment: I saw past posts in stack overflow used eval(), so I just tried to follow the notation there. I am guessing I no longer need it?

Comment: yes, because `eval(1)` gives 1 anyway and `eval(2)` is 2.

Comment: Why does `dt1[ctr, ctr + 1]` give me an answer of `2` but assigning it to 1 works? Shouldnt it give me 0, as thats the value of dt at row 1 col 2?